# How to fix "PATH" issue?

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library, python-tesseract

I  have created a program that prints image as text.

**Environment Variable**

- Variable name : pytesseract
- Variable value:    pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd=
  r'C:\Program Files    (x86)\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'

//code

```
try:
    from PIL import Image
except ImportError:
    import Image
import pytesseract

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd= r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'

image1 = Image.open("C:\python\program\image.png")

print(pytesseract.image_to_string(image1))
```

**Error** :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/python/program/Image_OCR.py", line 13, in <module>
    print(pytesseract.image_to_string(image1))
  File "C:\python\venv\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 338, in image_to_string
    }[output_type]()
  File "C:\python\venv\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 337, in <lambda>
    Output.STRING: lambda: run_and_get_output(*args),
  File "C:\python\venv\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 246, in run_and_get_output
    run_tesseract(**kwargs)
  File "C:\python\venv\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 222, in run_tesseract
    raise TesseractError(proc.returncode, get_errors(error_string))

pytesseract.pytesseract.TesseractError: (1, 'Error opening data file \\Program Files (x86)\\Tesseract-OCR\\tessdata/eng.traineddata Please make sure the TESSDATA_PREFIX environment variable is set to the parent directory of your "tessdata" directory. Failed loading language \'eng\' Tesseract couldn\'t load any languages! Could not initialize tesseract.')
```

**Actual result**: Print image as text.

Comment: set `TESSDATA_PREFIX` environment variable to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR`

Comment: after changes, it will show the same error.

Comment: add `import os; os.environ['TESSDATA_PREFIX']='C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR'`

Comment: try it, but didn't work...same error

Comment: It seems to be unable to find `\\Program Files (x86)\\Tesseract-OCR\\tessdata/eng.traineddata` so you are either not telling it the correct place or you don't have that file. Please clarify the situation as regards to those two possibilities.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I am using Ubuntu. I commented the below line `pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = '/app/.apt/usr/bin/tesseract'`  
 
It worked for me.  
 
Try removing/commenting the line  
 
`pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd= r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe`